# Peer-to-peer video chat application?

Tags: video, streaming, chat, p2p, peer-to-peer

I use Skype to video chat with my parents, but Skype video quality is very poor on my network. However, connecting directly to the other person's webcam works great.

I am looking for a [P2P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) video chat application for Windows, that would work over WAN and connect directly to an IP address and port.

I can't find anything that does not route via a third-party server.

What should I choose?

Comment: what about web service? there is a lot flash based p2p video chats.

Comment: What makes you think Skype isn't point to point?  Unless you have firewalls that are blocking things, the audio/video payloads should be going from point to point.  Fire up wireshark and actually look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [H.323](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.323) and [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) can used for point-to-point connections, and there are many programs that support both protocols. But both these protocols require a lot more work to get reliably working through a firewall, or router doing network address translation.

As far as easy of use, Skype, [Google Voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Voice), and other [IM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_messaging)-based clients tend to be much easier to get working, and are generally fine.

What makes you think Skype isn't point-to-point? Unless you have firewalls that are blocking things, the audio/video payloads should be going from point to point. Fire up [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) and actually look. At least in my tests on a unfiltered connection the audio/video payload **is point-to-point**. Only some control stuff goes to the master.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why skype quality is so low. Running wireshark is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) can connect [directly to the peer](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Documentation#Calling_IP_to_IP_directly).